# SQLite search with text style

Tags: android

I have a sqlite file. I want a query sqlite with a paramecter is normal text. But sqlite file have bold text. What query I do ?

EX: my paramecter is "lum" and sqlite file is "**lum**".

Thanh in advances.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "sqlite file have bold text". Do you means there is a table in the database that contains records with bold text ?

Comment: there is no way to actually store letters in bold in anywhere alone,all the text properties are actually fromatting which are applied in top of it. Charecters are always stored in a proper encodings such as ASCII, so your question sound out of world to me. Infact if you search with parameter "lum" you would get result "lum"(In Bold, as per you) as output.

Comment: I think, if You store a String for example in Bold like : <b>Hello</b>, it will be recognized as only a string in SQLite, but if get back the String with the cursor, You can set for example a text into textView like this: mYourTextView.setText(Html.fromhtml(yourboldstring));